# Is there a way to use sed in a bash script to remove text from a Microsoft Word Document?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, indexing

I need to remove  a bunch of index positions from MS Word documents that create a book. After revealing hidden text, all the index positions have the format of { XE "somethinghere" }. The question that I have is will sed be able to delete the text even though its not a line by line file? The Word documents have text boxes, charts, etc., so I was wondering if sed will be able to replace the XE term with nothing, therefor removing that particular index position.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter the term you wish to remove from the index:
read term
prefix="XE"
suffix="\"$term\""
newterm="$prefix $suffix"
echo $newterm   

for file in $(find ./ -name "*.doc"); do
  filename=${file:3}
  echo $filename
  sed "s/$newterm//" "$filename"
  echo Success  
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't get your hopes up. most unix tools, including sed are designed for files that have a Ctrl-J char delimiting each line of data, with limited support for other Ctrl chars, and NO support for null chars AND no real support for binary data. When I just looked at a docx file, I also see Uni-code chars. So, there may be versions of sed that support that, but you'll have to call it with the correct env-vars LANG=?? etc (search here for examples). YOu're much better off figuring out how to do what you need using Word-Basic, or one of the MS-Windows Basics variants. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
$ cat file
aslkdalsdmkaldmkaslfmdkalmkal{ XE "somethinghere" }amskldmakldmakl{ XE "otherthinghere" }alskjdkaldjakl
$ sed 's/\({ *XE *\)"[^"]*" *\(}\)/\1\2/g' file
aslkdalsdmkaldmkaslfmdkalmkal{ XE }amskldmakldmakl{ XE }alskjdkaldjakl
```

As you can see, the quoted parts in the `{ XE }` have been removed using a global substitution.

---

#### update

If you want to remove the section entirely, that's simpler:

```
sed 's/{ *XE[^}]*}//g' file
```

This removes

- `{`
- any number of spaces
- `XE`
- any number of characters that aren't `}`
- `}`

Comment: Is there a way where I can use this to completely eliminate the { XE } from the file as well?